# Zero-pad alphanumeric strings in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, alphanumeric, zero-pad

I would like to add zeros to an alphanumeric string if it's one digit.

What I've got is something like :

CV-1-1A
CV-1-32
CV-12-24
CV-1-2
CV-1-2A

and I would like to change it to:

CV-01-01A
CV-01-32
CV-12-24
CV-01-02
CV-01-02A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LPAD` can be used to zero-pad (or pad with any character, for that matter) a string.
However, it can't work inside a string, so some trickery is required.
Assuming all your values have the format of `a-b-c` where `a`, `b` and `c` are strings up to 3 characters, you could use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` to break the string up into parts, `LPAD` each part individually, and use `CONCAT` to put them all back together:

```
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, '-', 1), 
       '-',
       LPAD(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, '-', 2), '-', -1), 2, '0'), 
       '-',
       LPAD(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, '-', -1), 3, '0'))
FROM t;
```

Here's an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/316b20/12/0) with a working example.